# How to scroll recyclerview video frame with videoPlayer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, exoplayer, android-ffmpeg

[image]

I'm developing video editor app with the use of `ffmpeg` and `exoplayer`. I'm looking for a way to scroll a frames RecyclerView programmatically when video is playing. Here below app screenshot is given. Video frames already added in `recyclerview`  but i haven't idea about `recyclerview` scroll with video player.

Answer (score 0):

After searching of one day finally i got solution to displaying a custom timeline for a video playlist. Thanks [Shashank Mishra](https://medium.com/@shkcodes?source=post_page-----3d36ed7c9650--------------------------------) for your article.

[Article link](https://proandroiddev.com/building-a-video-timeline-using-recyclerview-3d36ed7c9650)

[github demo](https://github.com/shkcodes/VideoTimeline)

[image]